# What exactly is 'supply' on the 'supply vs demand' equation to determine the price of a token?

Tags: solidity, tokens, exchanges, price, tokenomics

We know that the price of a token is always a balance between supply and demand. Whenever I check what supply is, I get vague definitions. So I would like to hear your opinions about what **exactly** supply refers to. I have 4 options:

- total supply
- circulating supply
- 'traded supply' I just invented this concept as the number of tokens existing in the LP of the exchanges). Is there any existing name for this concept?
- any other option?

I think total supply is very innacurate to correlate with price because you can have locked tokens or tokens in vesting period. For circulating supply, I would accept that it is threat to sudden price changes, but not responsible directly of the price at a certain moment. My guess is that the supply in the supply vs demand equation is only what I call **the traded supply, i.e. the number of tokens in the LPs of the exchanges at a certain moment.**

But I never read this so this is why i am raising this question.

What is your opinion? Can you provide any reference clariying this point?

Answer (score 1):

`Supply` refers to the total number of tokens that are available for trading on the market when used in the **supply vs demand equation** to determine the price of a token.

It includes tokens that have already been `released` and are in circulation, as well as tokens that will be available in the future.

Comment: how can, tokens that have been held in a wallet for 10 years, and therefore are part of the circulating supply, influde in current price?